Pushing a branch from a local repo to a separate clone of the same remote repo on the same Windows machine
I have a Git repository, let's call it Foo, which I have cloned twice on the same Windows machine. Let's call the two local repositories Foo1 (in C:\repos\Foo1) and Foo2 (in C:\repos\Foo2).
Now the reason I have two clones is that I sometimes need to work on different branches at the time: for instance, I may be working on a feature branch on the "working" local repo Foo1, but then I need to release an urgent hotfix on main and I don't want (or cannot) switch away from the feature branch, so I just move to Foo2 and use that for the urgent hotfix. However, the actual reason is irrelevant: I just explained it to clarify the setup.
I have a branch I'm working on in Foo1, and another one I'm working on in Foo2. None of these branches are ready to be published, and since I may want to rebase them on main in the future, I'd rather not push them to the remote origin (i.e., Foo) that they share.
I want to check if the changes in the branch2 branch from Foo2 can fix the problems that developed because of the changes in the branch1 branch from Foo1. I want to "push" branch2 to Foo1 and rebase branch1 onto it. However, none of the two repos is bare, and they're also on a Windows machine, so I don't know if it's even possible (let alone recommended) to do such a thing.
Can I somehow "share" a branch between the two local repos without pushing/pulling it to/from the remote?

Your scenario sounds like a great example for using the command git worktree.

Manage multiple working trees attached to the same repository. A git repository can support multiple working trees, allowing you to check out more than one branch at a time.

Basically, instead of having two clones of the same repository where one of the two (foo1) is added as a second remote for the other (foo2) to sync changes, you could have one repository with its main worktree (foo1) for your development, and a second worktree (foo2) in a different external directory for your fix.
Both worktrees would be under the same repository, allowing you to have two branches checked out at the same time, switch between them, and perform any operation you would normally do under a repo with a single worktree.
In your case, to bring your scenario into a two-worktree repository, you could temporarily push the commits from the hotfix branch to your remote, fetch them on foo1, delete the hotfix branch from the remote, and finally create a second worktree from the newly fetched branch.
# enter foo2...

# push to the remote
git push origin hotfix

# enter foo1...

# fetching the hotfix
git fetch origin hotfix

# deleting the hotfix branch from the remote
git push --delete origin hotfix

# create a second worktree in a directory named hotfix with a new branch (hotfix) checked out pointing to origin/hotfix
git worktree add -b hotfix ../hotfix origin/hotfix


This is great to know! But how does it help me with my question: can I somehow "share" branches between the worktrees?

@Simone since both worktrees are under the same local repository, you can have multiple branches checked out at the same time. Like so, you don't need to abandon your work on foo1, and continue with a new worktree (foo2 or hotfix) for your fixes. Right now those fix commits are just under foo2. So, if I were you, I would temporarily push them to your remote, fetch on foo1, and then delete the fix branch from the remote. Then, create a new worktree from the fetched branch.

This works great! It's like commits on the worktrees are immediately synced (I understood your explanation, all the worktrees belong to the same repository). I'll accept your answer, because it has even introduced me to a great new feature of Git. TY!

Yeah, they're not really syncing, but rather working under the same repo. That's why you immediately see each other's changes. If you check the .git folder under the second worktree, you'll see that it just points to the first repo.
